# How to change file encoding from hexadecimal to UTF-8

Tags: node.js, batch-file, encoding

I have a log file from virtual terminal that looks like this:

```
0025 0200 c7c8 da20 0d00 2c01 0400 3d01
1822 0000 0012 a0f5 cd02 2810 0030 0010
0030 0110 0030 0210 0030 0310 0030 0410
0030 0510 0030 0610 0030 0710 0030 0810
0030 0a87 1332 203c 1000 3000 0011 1000
3001 0010 1000 3002 0000 1000 3003 0000
1000 3004 0000 1000 3005 0000 1000 3006
................
```

By default the program`Hercules(serial terminal)` that append to the log file AFAIK doesn't have the ability to change the log file encoding. So when I open the file with `Sublime Text 3` it shows that the file is encoded with `hexadecimal` encoding. The problem arises when I use the text from the file in `nodejs` is not converted properly to a string.

For now I found the solution to change the file encoding to UTF-8 manually with ST3 File -> Save With Encoding -> UTF-8. But it will happen very often and for many files, so some automation would harm.

The question is: Can I change the file encoding using `node.js` or `batch` script, from `hexadecimal` to `UTF-8`?

Comment: Is the shown content of your file meant literally, or is this just a hex. dump?

Comment: I think it is a hex dump. When save the file with UTF-8 the size grows from 9kB to 22kB.

Comment: What happens when you try the following: `certutil -decodehex "log-file.hex" "log-file.txt"` im Windows command prompt (in the directory the log file resides), supposing `log-file.hex` is the log file you show in the question?

Comment: @aschipfl I get the following message:

DecodeFile returned The data is invalid. 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
CertUtil: -decodehex command FAILED: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
CertUtil: The data is invalid.

Comment: I think it is a binary file, but can't find the encoding.